# Data structure(none-type to float)

Tags: python, pandas

Converting None-type to a float. Using slice notation, I cut a part of a string from a text returning as a none-type. Problem is conversion of that part of the string to a float where  i can easily divide it by a number.

```
sval = print(line[20:])
fval = float(sval)
```

Excepting the mnemonic sval to be converted to a float. Gives a trace back, that none-type conversion argument must be a string or number.

Comment: The problem is that you are assign the result of calling `print` to `sval`, and `print` **always** returns `None`!

Answer (score 2):

The `print` function doesn't return any value, so `sval` is always `None` regardless of the right side.
Please try  the following:

```
>>> line = '12345678'  # string
>>> sval = line[4:]
>>> fval = float(sval)
>>> fval
5678.0
```

**FYI:** Here's a brief explanation about the `None` type in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/constants.html#None).
In a nutshell, you can't convert `None` to `float`. Therefore, `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'` can be translated into *"Oh, I can't find any clue in `sval`!"*